# check if a record exists in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a people table used to track user online activities. I'd like to check if any user from a group is online or not with following query:

```
Person.where(:person_id => candidates, :online => true).present?
```

notes: candidates present the group of people; online attribute will be true if user is online

I realize such query is not efficient enough because it returns all the qualified users then check presence. Is there any better way to do the same thing more efficiently?

Thank

Comment: Why not `Person.where(id: <your user's id>, online: true).present?`.

Comment: Why not `Person.exists?(:person_id => candidates, :online => true)`?

Comment: it could be fast if it stops as soon as it finds a match.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `COUNT` query would be more efficient:

```
Person.where(:person_id => candidates, :online => true).count
```

You can then just compare with `0`:

```
Person.where(:person_id => candidates, :online => true).count > 0
```

Comment: count and present are equivalent in rails. They are all using COUNT from mysql.

Comment: Not true; I just ran two queries against my local rails (4.2.3), the present one uses `SELECT *...` and the count one uses `SELECT COUNT(*)`, though I appreciate this may differ between versions.

Comment: Ah, well there you are... the most recent release of 2.x is nearly 3 years old!  In fact rails 2 [first came out](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions) in December 2007!

Comment: yeah, upgrade is not an easy thing, many functions depends on that.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
people = Person.select(:id, :online).where(id: candidate_ids)
```

then unless people.blank? loop through people and check whether they are online and do whatever you need to do with the people who are online. Using select doesn't load the entire object, only the things you need. Then when you say:

```
person.online
```

It's not a query, you're just getting it from an array. As a bonus, if you only have an individual user, .select also works with .find.